# 'Undefined' when using OOP and AJAX login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, undefined

ive got the following ajax call, which appears to be working(as in the form submits, the loader shows etc)

```
<?PHP
session_start();

include('includes/class.login.php');

$login = new Login();

$token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

if ($_POST['ajax']) {
    exit($login->getStatus());
}

?>
<style>
    #message { display: none; cursor: pointer; }
    .loader { display: none; }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
        $(this).fadeOut(300);
        $('.loader').delay(300).fadeIn(100);
        $.post("<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>", { username: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val(), ajax: true }).done(function(data) {
            if (data.logged_in == 1) {
                // Redirect with javascript
                $('.loader').delay(2000).fadeOut(100);
                $('#message').html('<p>Success! We\'ll redirect you in a minute...</p>'+data.logged_in).delay(2200).fadeIn(200);
            } else {
                // Inject errors to html
                // data.errors
                $('.loader').delay(2000).fadeOut(100);
                $('#message').html('<p>Failed... Click to try again!'+data.errors+data.logged_in).delay(2200).fadeIn(200);
                $('#message').on('click', function(){
                    $(this).fadeOut(200);
                    $('#loginForm').delay(350).fadeIn(200);
                });
            }
        }); 
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$token;?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In"/>
</form>
<div class="loader">
    <img src="loader.gif"/>
</div>
<div id="message"></div>
```

You'll see in my message outputs i've tried appending data.errors and data.logged_in to find out what values they are holding, however they both just come back as undefined.

The JSON code in my php class is this:

```
public function getStatus()
    {
        return json_encode(
            array(
                'logged_in' => $this->isLoggedIn(), 
                'errors' => $this->showErrors()
            )
        );
    }
```

Entire PHP class:

```
<?PHP

class Login 
{
    private $_id;
    private $_username;
    private $_password;
    private $_passmd5;

    private $_errors;
    private $_access;
    private $_login;
    private $_token;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_errors = array();
        $this->_login  = isset($_POST['login']) ? 1 : 0;
        $this->_access = 0;
        $this->_token  = $_POST['token'];

        $this->_id     = 0;
        $this->_username = ($this->_login) ? $this->filter($_POST['username']) : $_SESSION['username'];
        $this->_password = ($this->_login) ? $this->filter($_POST['password']) : '';
        $this->_passmd5  = ($this->_login) ? md5($this->_password) : $_SESSION['password'];

    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        ($this->_login) ? $this->verifyPost() : $this->verifySession();

        return $this->_access;
    }

    public function filter($var)
    {
        return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/','',$var);
    }

    public function verifyPost()
    {
        try
        {
            if(!$this->isTokenValid())
                throw new Exception('Invalid form submission');

            if(!$this->isDataValid())
                throw new Exception('Invalid form data entered');

            if(!$this->verifyDatabase())
                throw new Exception('Invalid username/password combination');

        $this->_access = 1;
        $this->registerSession();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $this->_errors[] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function verifySession()
    {
        if($this->sessionExist() && $this->verifyDatabase())
            $this->_access = 1;
    }

    public function verifyDatabase()
    {
        include('dbConfig.php');

        $data = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_username = '{$this->_username}' AND user_password = '{$this->_passmd5}'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($data))
        {
            list($this->_id) = @array_values(mysql_fetch_assoc($data));
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function isDataValid()
    {
        return (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]/', $this->_username) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]/', $this->_password)) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    public function isTokenValid()
    {
        return (!isset($_SESSION['token']) || $this->_token != $_SESSION['token']) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public function registerSession()
    {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $this->_id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $this->_username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $this->_passmd5;
    }

    public function sessionExist()
    {
        return (isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    public function showErrors()
    {
        echo "<h3>Errors</h3>";
        foreach($this->_errors as $key=>$value)
            echo $value."<br>";
    }

    public function getStatus()
    {
        return json_encode(
            array(
                'logged_in' => $this->isLoggedIn(), 
                'errors' => $this->showErrors()
            )
        );
    }   
}

?>
```

isLoggedIn should be displaying either a 0 or 1 and showErrors shows an array of errors, but i'm getting nothing :(

Comment: Are you "echoing" the return of the method in the page?

Comment: Hopefully your PHP code contains something more, like a class and an echo statement to display the JSON etc ?

Comment: let me upload my php class, 2 secs

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(data)` before `if (data.logged_in == 1) {`

Comment: console log comes back as <h3>Errors</h3>{"logged_in":0,"errors":null} however, i typed in the correct login data, so it should be a 1!

Comment: And where exactly are you calling that class? Also, you are returning an array that has a function full of echo statements in showErrors(), when what you should be doing us just echoing the JSON.

Comment: I've added all the code i'm using to the question so you should be able to see where everything is being called etc. And that may be true, however why is it that when i enter the correct login isLoggedIn still comes back as a 0 and not 1? its really frustrating :( lol

Comment: Good shout on the errors btw, that isn't returning null now i've removed it calling a php function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you are actually outputting your json array. When you output the JSON try putting the following line before it or use your framework to basically make sure you're outputting JSON headers.

```
if ($_POST['ajax']) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $login->getStatus();
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Well i've added data.errors to the jquery that outputs the html into the #message div and i though that'd display the data from the array. I may have done this completely wrong. All the code is up there, but for whatever reason, even with the right login info, it's not working. ill try and work out where to put this line

Comment: I updated my code snippet after I found your output statement.

Comment: Cheers budydy i'll give this a shot :)

Comment: THIS IS SO CLOSE! haha. It's not undefined any more, yet for some reason it's still really confused when it's trying to get the isLoggedIn stuff. Have i slipped up somewhere? It's still returning 0 with all the right info, should be a 1

Comment: Are you able to debug the PHP errors on the server in the logs? Or use Google Chrome's javascript console/developer tools to see if any of those exceptions are being thrown? You might need to back trace through that script to find the issue. Your next project should be learning test driven development and PDO as unit tests are designed for just this type of debugging :)

Comment: Cool. Seriously my friend, check out http://us3.php.net/pdo , mysql_ functions are deprecated. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try making a non-AJAX form in a static file and submitting it to your PHP script. Do you get the JSON data back that you expect?

Another way to see the data is to use the network tab in your browser's developer tools (I'm used to Chrome, but other browsers have similar tools). This will tell you if the fault is in the Javascript on the client or the PHP on the server.

Comment: Well, i've tried this and everything was fine. MOST of this OOP approach is fine, its literally the last hurdle! I've done a console log for data and this returned:
<h3>Errors</h3>{"logged_in":0,"errors":null}
which means it's trying to display the errors, which is good. But it's not displaying what error, and also... This was created using correct login details, so it should be returning a 1 and not a 0 haha

Comment: You need to fix the PHP to not include the `<h3>Errors</h3>` when the response is JSON.

Comment: this is the function for the errors now:
public function showErrors()
 {
  foreach($this->_errors as $key=>$value)
   echo $value."<br>";
 }

i've removed the h3 tags etc, and now when i do a console log i get {"logged_in":0,"errors":null} which is still wrong, because there are errors and this is still occuring when the right login info is entered